# how to find getnumPartitions on pyspark.pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

The pyspark documentation says that the pandas-on-spark is distributed. If I create a dataframe using `pyspark.pandas.read_csv('file.csv')`, how can I know the number of partitions of the pandas dataframe? Do we have an equivalent to `df.rdd.getNumPartition()` for pandas-on-spark dataframe?

Comment: pandas API in Pyspark is an expensive operation to the best of my knowledge. To read csv we can use spark.read.csv.Once you use the  df=pyspark.pandas.read_csv('file.csv') .please let me know if I missed anything.